# How does the line search in geometry optimisations work?

Tags: python, gaussian, geometry-optimization, optimization, pyberny

I am trying to write a Newton-Raphson geometry optimisation script in python ([Current version of my code](https://gitlab.com/erjvd/newton_raphson_gaussian/-/tree/main)) using the energy, gradient and Hessian from Gaussian 16. In order to reach a minimum, I would need to add a line search, and possibly also add a trust region, but I am struggling to understand how it works (in Cartesian coordinates, with an analytical Hessian). I read the book of Fletcher and had a look at the pyBerny code, but it doesn't work so far.

Without a line search, no minimum is found; the molecule's energy increases and it breaks apart. If I use code based on the pyBerny package, no fit can be found.

Are there any obvious problems with my line search code?

Comment: +1 Welcome to our forum!

Comment: It's very, very difficult to help when you just say "it doesn't work" How does it not work? Wrong answers? Crashes? Exactly what? But really to make progress we will need to see the code - a one dimensional line search shouldn't be very long, can you edit your question to include it, along with sample input *and* output so we can check we see the same as you?

Comment: I can't write a detailed answer right now, but the line searches in Gaussian16 are generally approximate, polynomial fitted line search. You take the gradients at two points, project them along the vector connecting the two coordinates, and then fit a cubic or constrained quartic polynomial to the energies and directional gradients. Then you take the minimum of that polynomial, subject to the condition that it is not too far from either point. Then you generate a new gradient by interpolation/extrapolation. And then another new step.

Comment: Also, I would suggest using rational function optimisation, as the implementation is simpler than trust radius quasi-newton model (although performance may or may not be as good)

Comment: Thank you for the replies so far! I have added a link to my code.

Comment: I certainly don't have the time to review your code. It's probably easier to look at an existing linesearch code. Google turns up https://medium.com/practical-coding/line-search-methods-in-optimization-dee49c1dec0c

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: If I run it for an ethane molecule with a slightly rotated dihedral, it writes " No fit succeeded, staying in new point" at the second step. The quartic fit returns -50, and the cubic fit None. Hence, I obtain the original coordinates back and the script stops.

Comment: If I uncomment the function to check if my Hessian is positive definite (if not, values on the diagonal are increased using the code from the link Geoff posted above), the script runs for 23 steps, but the energy increases for several steps and the molecule breaks apart.